# Box2D | Resize fixture without destroying/recreating?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I want to dynamically change a fixtures size. Originally I would destroy the fixture every frame, then recreate it with the new size. The problem with this is that since I am recreating fixtures every frame, the ContactListener is screwed up because it will call beginContact and endContact each frame (since I keep destroying/recreating the fixture). Is there any way around this? I need the contact listener to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [this](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Shape.html#setRadius-float-) (if you're using the radius as a size).

In your `ContactListener` you can access the Fixtures of your bodies, for example (**using Kotlin**):

```
override fun beginContact(contact: Contact) {
    contact.fixtureA.body.fixtureList[0].shape.radius *= 0.99f
    contact.fixtureB.body.fixtureList[0].shape.radius *= 0.99f
}
```

This will decrease the radius of two contacting circle shaped bodies at 1 percent. I Hope this helps a bit.